# Leetcode #35 Search Insert Position (list index out of range)

Tags: python

```
    test=[]     
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        
        if nums[i+1] > target > nums[i]:
            test.append(nums[i])
            test.append(target)
        else:
            test.append(nums[i])
    
    return test.index(target)
```

I try to create new array sort the value first, then find the index of the target.
It get error in index out of range in line nums[i+1].
How can I correct the code without the big change

Question link: https://leetcode.com/problems/search-insert-position/

Comment: This is because you are using `nums[i+1] ` and since `i ` is in the `range 0 to len(nums)` it gives index out of range for last value of `i`

Comment: iterate to penultimate index: `for i in range(len(nums)-1):`

Comment: @Rafaó  I tried, but have some case can't work. How can I improve the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What you are doing wrong:

This is because you are using `nums[i+1]` and since `i` is in the `range 0 to len(nums)` it gives `index out of range` for the last value of `i`.

You are checking if an element in `nums` is greater than the previous element or not. This will always be true because `nums` is sorted. I also don't know why are you appending the `nums[i+1]` and `target` to the `test` list. There's no need to create a new list.

### What the question asks you to do

It tells you that the `nums` is sorted and you need to return the index if `target` is in `nums`. If not then return the index where it should be inserted. **NOTE: It doesn't ask you to insert the target**.

### So, the steps which you can follow are:

1. Loop through `nums`. You can use `for i, num in enumerate(len(nums)):`. This will give you the index i.e. `i` and the value of each element in nums i.e. `num`.
2. Take each element to check if the `target` is greater than or equal to `nums[i]`.
3. If it is then you need to return that index because that would be the index where the `target` needs to be inserted. Eg: [1,3,6,8] if `target` is 5 then it should be inserted at 2 which is the index of `nums[i] > target`.
4. If `target` is greater than the last element of `nums` then return the last index of `nums` i.e. `len(nums)`.

### Combining all steps. The code we get(Do try it yourself first! Spoiler Alert!):

> ```
> def searchInsert(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
>
>     for i, num in enumerate(nums):
>         if num >= target:
>             return i
>
>
>     return len(nums)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
int searchInsert(int A[], int n, int target) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = n;
    int mid = 0;
    while (left<right) {
       mid = (left + right) / 2;
       if (A[mid]<target) {
          left = mid + 1;
       }
       else if (A[mid]>target) {
          right = mid;
       }
       else {
          return mid;
       }
    }
    return left;
}
```

Try this code using C format at Leetcode you will pass..